# User Control Spacing Blows Up When Placed In Main Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, user-controls, spacing

I have a C# WinForms application I am developing with Visual Studio 2010. My application has a custom control (User Control). When I am designing the custom control here is what it looks like:

[image: User Control]

Note the very narrow space between the image, label, and combo box.

When I add the custom control to my main form here is what it looks like:

[image: User Control In Form]

Notice how much more space there is between the controls as compared to the spacing in the first image.

I have no idea where this extra spacing is coming from. It's as if the margin/padding between the controls is getting multiplied by some scale factor of which I have no idea how it's determined.

I have tried changing the padding/margins on both the custom control and the main form but nothing seems to work.

Does anyone know why this extra space shows up?

Thank you.

Comment: Check the docking and anchoring of the controls within your user control

Comment: Do the coordinates of your controls change in your code (in runtime) ?

Comment: Both screenshots are from the designer not when running the ap. When I run the app nothing changes. The spacing exists exactly as it does when in the designer.

Comment: Dock is set to None and anchor is default (Top, Left).

Comment: @Stefan should I put debug print statements in to check the coordinates at runtime?

Comment: @JanTacci No, if you see this in your designer (and not at runtime), my suggestion is not relevant. I didn't notice the extra space was visible in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

I can see only two reasons for such behavior - either you have wrong `Dock` / `Anchor` settings (issue is reproduced when you have `Dock` set to `None` and `Anchor` to `Top` only), or your image, label and combobox are sitting in cells of some other control, like `TableLayoutPanel` which adjusts width of cells. Thus you don't have any additional container, then check *very carefully* `Dock` and `Anchor` settings of *each* of the controls (image, label and combobox). Also check if you change these properties at runtime (also check `Margin`, `Location` and `Padding`).

Comment: I will do that now. The controls and the general layout of my form are very simple at the moment so I doubt there will be any *hidden* panel, etc. causing this behavior.